# uwp mediacapture record to multiple files

Tags: uwp, video-capture

I am developing a UWP app that records webcam output to a file using the MediaCapture class.  I need to find a means of sending this record output to two files concurrently and was interested in finding out if there is a direct means of doing this with the same mediacapture class or do I need to create an entirely separate class instance.

Comment: It seems we can not use the one `MediaCapturePreviewer` to record 2 files at same time, we also can not initialize 2 MediaCapturePreviewers at same time.

Comment: So I would have to write a custom sink to do this?  Is there an example of this anywhere?